# Vue JS button click redirecting to 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

I have the following component in my laravel/Vue application.

When the user clicks on this button I want to send them to the `privacy blade`. `(sample.site/privacy-policy)`

```
<template lang="">
  <div class="verbatimGameLayout__footer">
    <FeedbackButton label="Vie privée" :onClick="goToFeedback" />
    <SaveButton label="sauvgarder" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  components: {
    FeedbackButton
  },
  methods: {
    goToFeedback() {
      window.location = "/privacy-policy";
    }
  }
};
```

And I have my route as follows in `web.php`,

```
Route::get('/privacy-policy', 'SecurityImplementationController@privacy');
```

When I try to access the URL it kept giving me a 404 error...

Following is the controller (`SecurityImplementationController.php`) method  related to the mentioned issue

```
public function privacy() {
        return view('privacy');
    }
```

Comment: ```
Route::get('/privacy-policy', 'SecurityImplementationController@privacy');
``` Why does your route have a slash at the beginning? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: you  should probably use: `window.location.href=...` in your function

Comment: nope, it's not working either

Comment: In vue.js you should bind the onclick like this "v-on:click" instead of ':onClick'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you clean your route cache and check

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `vue-router` for actions like this.

Using `vue-router` you can easily set up routes like that:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```

Then you can call a route like this:

```
this.$router.push('/bar')
```

See further information in the docs: [Vue Router | Getting Started](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html)